# When click on image menu comes up after using lightbox2

Tags: css, z-index, lightbox2

Here is my code where I want to display images. I linked lightbox css and js properly and it's working, but when images is display it comes with menu bar which i don't want.

```
<div class="carousel-item <?php echo $isActive ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $photo['filepath']; ?>" data-lightbox="product-photos">
        <img src="<?php echo $photo['filepath']; ?>" alt="Product Image" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      </a>
</div>
```

I have attached screenshot of it for better understanding. Can anyone help me with this. Thank You.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQRPx.png)

Comment: The force you're looking for is called the z-order. And PHP has nothing to do with it, that's CSS. C.f. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: I have included z-index css, but not working.

Comment: [edit] your question and show what you did. share your understanding of the code, and what puzzles you that it does not work. compare [mre].